# What are necessary configuration require to get mean.js scaffolding via yo generator?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, mean-stack, meanjs

I have following versions of libraries.

`

```
nurv@nurvcoder:~/Node/demo$ node --version
v5.0.0
nurv@nurvcoder:~/Node/demo$ nodejs --version
v0.10.40
nurv@nurvcoder:~/Node/demo$ mean --version
0.10.14
nurv@nurvcoder:~/Node/demo$ yo --version
1.5.0
nurv@nurvcoder:~/Node/demo$ grunt --version
grunt-cli v0.1.13
nurv@nurvcoder:~/Node/demo$ bower --version
1.6.5
nurv@nurvcoder:~/Node/demo$ npm --version
3.3.12`
```

When I used `yo generator` to create the `mean` application

`

```
nurv@nurvcoder:~/Node/demo$ sudo yo meanjs`

`You're using the official MEAN.JS generator.
?What mean.js version would you like to generate?
`
`>0.4.0
 0.4.1`
```

And following error was thrown

```
`npm WARN engine karma@0.12.37: wanted: {"node":">=0.8 <=0.12 || >=1 <=2"} (current: {"node":"5.0.0","npm":"3.3.12"})
npm WARN install Couldn't install optional dependency: Unsupported
npm WARN install Couldn't install optional dependency: Unsupported
npm WARN prefer global jshint@2.8.0 should be installed with -g
npm WARN prefer global node-gyp@3.0.3 should be installed with -g
npm WARN prefer global nodemon@1.3.8 should be installed with -g
npm WARN prefer global node-inspector@0.10.2 should be installed with -g
make: g++: Command not found
make: *** [Release/obj.target/bufferutil/src/bufferutil.o] Error 127
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:270:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.19.0-32-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/satish/Node/demo/mean/node_modules/bufferutil
gyp ERR! node -v v5.0.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN install:bufferutil@1.2.1 bufferutil@1.2.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm WARN install:bufferutil@1.2.1 Exit status 1
make: g++: Command not found
make: *** [Release/obj.target/bufferutil/src/bufferutil.o] Error 127
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:270:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.19.0-32-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/nurv/Node/demo/mean/node_modules/node-inspector/node_modules/bufferutil
gyp ERR! node -v v5.0.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN install:bufferutil@1.1.0 bufferutil@1.1.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm WARN install:bufferutil@1.1.0 Exit status 1
make: g++: Command not found
make: *** [Release/obj.target/validation/src/validation.o] Error 127
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:270:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.19.0-32-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/satish/Node/demo/mean/node_modules/node-inspector/node_modules/utf-8-validate
gyp ERR! node -v v5.0.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok
```

`
A proper guidance to resolve this problem would be a great help.

Comment: Hmm, it says g++ not found?